# I am unable to set up env variables in my machine

Tags: maven

What are the steps setting up env variables in my machine?

I used path

```
Java_Home:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181;

Path :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.0-bin\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin

Maven_Home:C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.0-bin\apache-maven-3.6.0C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.0-bin\apache-maven-3.6.0
```

```
C:\Users\user 2>java -version
```

> java version "1.8.0_181"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

```
C:\Users\user 2>mvn --version
```

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run this program
>   NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
>
> 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA HOME should be

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
```

Your MAVEN HOME should be

```
MAVEN_HOME= D:\Software\apache-maven-3.6.0
```

Append path variable with following entry

```
Path :%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;
```